# TikZpicture/pgfplots: How to reduce quantity of displayed xticklabels when using "xticklabels from table"?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, labels, plot, ticks

I want to generate a simple x/y-diagram with data out of a data-table (~ 2000 values).

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\begin{filecontents}{Data_Table.csv}
X   Y
00:00   0
00:01   50
00:01   100
00:02   150
00:02   200
02:03   250
03:03   300
04:04   350
04:04   400
05:05   450
05:05   500
06:06   550
06:06   600
07:07   700
07:07   800
08:08   900
09:08   1000
12:09   1100
14:09   1200
14:10   1300
15:10   1400
16:11   1500
18:11   1600
20:12   1800
25:00   2000
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
       \begin{tikzpicture}
       \begin{axis}[
       width=0.5\textheight,      
       height=0.5\textheight,
       xlabel={Time [mm:ss]},
       ylabel={Measurement [mm]},
       xtick=data,
       xticklabels from table={Data_Table.csv}{X},
       xticklabel style={rotate=90,anchor=east},
       xmin = 0,
       ymin = 0,
       ymax = 2200,
       legend pos=outer north east,
       legend cell align=left,
       legend style={draw=none}]
       \addplot[color=black,mark=none] table [x expr=\coordindex,y=Y] {Data_Table.csv};
       \legend{Graph}
       \end{axis}
       \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image]

---

As you can see, there are far too many `xticklabels` displayed below the x-axis. How can I reduce the quantity (density) of shown `xticklabels`, e.g. to an interval of 5 minutes?

I think the common `xticks={5,10,15}`-command won't work because of the inclusion of `xticklabels` from the data-table (`xticklabels from table={Data_Table.csv}{X}`)...

---

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `each nth point={some number}`too `\addplot` options you can do what you want. E.g.,:

```
\addplot[color=black,mark=none, each nth point={2}] table [x expr=\coordindex,y=Y] {Data_Table.csv};
```

generates the following

[image]

Comment: This reduces also the data point density and not only the tick label density, right?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, I believe so. If you put for instance, `each nth point={10}`, you see that the shape of plot changes as well, hence, actual data is being reduced in frequency.

Comment: Ok. I think that the question is about the tick labels density independent from the data density.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, you are indeed right! I might remove the answer...

Comment: Let's wait what Dave has to say :)

Comment: Hey you two! Thank you very much for your pleasant help! Like Dr. Manuel Kuehner said, simply reducing the point-density wouldn't really cause a great precision for the resulting graph... :-)

Nevertheless, I didn't know this function until now. Thank you very much Pouya! In the meanwhile, I found an other solution for optimizing the visibility of the `xticks`: I didn't use the values from the table anymore but made my own ones with minute-values without a colon. So there are regular numerical values now, named by `xtick label`...